# What is the name of the tool that allows one to manipulate environment variables?

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

For some bizarre reason our corporation has disabled access to modify our own environment variables, they've actually set every single modifiable group policy to disallow us from doing anything, creating a huge amount of red tape.

I've now realised that while I can't manipulate my environment variables through the control panel, I can actually get to the screen by typing "Environment variable" into the start search and I can then execute `Edit environment variables for your account`.

I'm wondering what the application/target is that this executes to allow me to document this directly for a procedure.

Comment: What a bunch of mindless control freaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this (change Windows path to match your setup):

```
"C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe" sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

Comment: That's the ticket, thanks! Needed to unquote the `exe` though. :)

Comment: Any idea if there's a way to make my path appear before the system path? Need to override the systems installed java 1.5 to 1.8.